# Query to search on a keyword in the content of a PDF file with the ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I work a project with ASP.NET MVC 2 (C#) using the ADO.NET Entity Framework.
My database contains the path of a PDF file.  j'extrère the contents of the PDF file, and I put it in my table in a column of type ntex (SQL Server).

My problem is that I want to do a search by a keyword in the content of a PDF file.
I do not find the query (requète).

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN LIKE '%keyword2search%'
```

For more information on LIKE see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Also consider changing ntext because it is deprecated according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx